# Why does font become pixelated when using babel or fontenc?

Tags: fonts

If you get close enough, you can see the pixelation, but if you remove the babel or fontenc package, the font will again become vector

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\begin{document}
L  Д
\end{document}
```

[image]

pixelated font

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}

\begin{document}
L  
\end{document}
```

[image]

normal vector font

Comment: install the cm-super package.

Comment: I tried but either I'm stupid or this package was not installed properly, but when using the T2A encoding and babel, everything becomes pixelated again. Maybe it's because I'm using pdflatex.

Comment: no I'm using pdflatex too. Show your log-file (of the example with the pixel fonts).

Comment: I can't access that, copy it into the question

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TpIZVyzDbeCoGZMmDnSiIDTr2D1IV4_Z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: do not use links, add the log to the question but `<C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\fonts/pk/ljfour/lh/lh-t2a/dpi600\larm1000.pk>` is a bitmap I get `</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>
` from cm-super if i uncomment the lines

Comment: try if it works if you update the font map files (miktex console, user mode, menu tasks, refresh font map files).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes! it worked. Thanks a lot.